# Is it justifiable to closely mimic the structure/organisation of another thesis for your own thesis

Tags: thesis, plagiarism

I am currently in the process of writing my masters thesis. During my research I found this another thesis and I really like the way it is organised and structured.

By structure, I mean the heading titles, the organisation of results and their order etc, for one chapter only. Although the topic of both thesis are similar but I will be presenting my own original data and results in the thesis.

Would it be ok for me to closely copy the structure of another thesis or could that be seen as plagiarism?

Comment: Is your plan to use it as a starting point for yours? Or to use it for yours?

Comment: It is almost certainly mandatory.

Answer (score 33):

Generally, as the purpose of the thesis is to convey *information* and as you are not plagiarizing the content, it should be fine to follow the organizational structure of another work, especially if it serves that purpose.

After all, most publications encourage or enforce some kind of organizational or structural guidelines in their papers.

Answer (score 9):

It is usually fine to copy the organizational structure
of another thesis or journal article.
However, you should take a short pause just to think through
whether that is the best way to structure your own writing.

As an aside, in some fields, it is almost *mandatory*
to write your article/thesis to follow a certain organizational structure.
For example, virtually all original journal articles
in the health sciences follow
a very standardized structure known as
introduction, methods, results, and discussion (IMRAD).

**Source:**
Sollaci, Luciana B., and Mauricio G. Pereira.
"The introduction, methods, results, and discussion (IMRAD) structure: a fifty-year survey."
*Journal of the Medical Library Association* 92.3 (2004): 364.